# Jasmine não está reconhecendo a função getCurrentNavigation()

Tags: angular, jasmine

Estou tentando testar um componente que usa a função `getCurrentNavigation()` do Router para pegar dados através da navegação. Meu componente está funcionando normalmente com o propósito esperado quando o rodo com `ng serve`, porém meu teste está dizendo:

> Component2Component > should create TypeError:
>   this.router.getCurrentNavigation is not a function

Essa é a forma que eu pego a data do router:

```
constructor(public router: Router) {
  if (
    this.router.getCurrentNavigation() &&
    this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras
  ) {
    console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras);
  }
```

Meu teste:

```
describe('Component2Component', () => {
  let component: Component2Component;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component2Component>;
  const routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component2Component],
      imports: [CommonModule],
      providers: [{ provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component2Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Porque meu teste não está reconhecendo esta função?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se alguém passar por esse problema, eu resolvi importando o módulo `RouterTestingModule` na lista de imports de módulos do teste e removendo a declaração de `routerSpy` que eu criei (O módulo passa a gerenciar as funções e não o spy criado):

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component2Component],
      imports: [CommonModule, RouterTestingModule],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

E então a função passa a ser acessível.